# ProteinData Error: "Cannot import data as PDB format"

Tags: warning-messages, chemistry

I'm trying to use the Mathematica examples for plotting proteins:

[image]

But when I type the command I get the next error:

[image]

How can I import data as PDB format?

Comment: I encountered a problem with Wolfram Development Platform the first time I tried it. Afterwards it worked as it should. Please try the command again.

Comment: I tried the command again and it shows the same error

Comment: Update to Mathematica 11.3. Mathematica 10 is relatively old at this point.

Comment: The problem was that. Thanks

Comment: This isn't  reproducible for me. `ProteinData["A2M", "MoleculePlot"]` works for versions 9.0+